# How to configure Eclipse to "autosave before build" by default?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, autosave

I am working with Eclipse (Indigo) to develop C projects. When I create a new C project in a new workspace, by default the "Autosave before build" option is not set. This is extremely frustrating, as autosave is usually the default behavior in other IDE's I worked on. I change some code, build and nothing seems to go as expected - until I remember that the option is not set...

Is there a way to make Eclipse open a new workspace with this option set?

Comment: you mean there is an option in Eclipse where it auto saves for you? Really? :D

Comment: @Adrian - it took me some time and search to find out, but it hides in Window->Preferences->Workspace. I am just waiting to meet with the guy who decided on some of the eclipse design/environment defaults to strangle him with my bare hands...

Comment: hehe thanks for revealing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `default.ini`, or some other name, containing the following line:

```
org.eclipse.ui.ide/SAVE_ALL_BEFORE_BUILD=true
```

In your `eclipse.ini` file which already exists, add the following lines somewhere before the `-vmargs` line:

```
-pluginCustomization
/path/to/default.ini
```

Where `/path/to/default.ini` is the full path to the `default.ini` file you created in the first step. If Eclipse will be used by multiple users on this machine, `default.ini` should be accessible by all of them.

Comment: Thanks! What if I need it to be a relative path? What is the "working directory" this file is being processed at? Can I just put it in the same place as the `eclipse.ini` file (i.e., at the root of the eclipse installation) and discard the `/path/to/` part?

Comment: Just tried your method and it does not seem to work. I created the new file in the eclipse directory, then I added the 2nd line immediately before the `-vmargs` line and tried with and without the full path.

Comment: Further investigating, I don't seem to have a plugin named `org.eclipse.ui.ide`. I do have two other named: `org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.7.0.I20110519-0100.jar` and `org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.0.300.I20110306-2000.jar`. Or is the 1st one the one I'm looking for?

Comment: OK, I have found it! Searching the eclipse forum, I found a similar post with a similar solution - the problem is that the `/path/to/def.ini` should be on the **next line**. I guess this is what you meant in "add the following lines". Probably a formatting problem.

Comment: [edited the answer to add the newline - waiting for peer review]

Comment: Still looking for a solution to avoid absolute path, though.

Comment: @ysap: Thanks for adding the newline. I should've been more explicit about the formatting error. I couldn't figure out how to fix it myself. I'm not sure how to avoid using an absolute path.

Comment: Is there a reason for not setting this via UI?

Answer (score 9):

if 
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and there you can check "Save automatically before build" + "Build automatically"

don't work try this

**Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> "Save dirty editors before launching"**

Comment: I also had to check "Build (if required) before launching"

Comment: First option doesn't exist on Eclipse 4.9 anymore  . This `Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> "Save dirty editors before launching"` is correct , thank you ma lord :)

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse CDT Kepler you can set it in:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Save automatically before build
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question.